How can I create a quantum fluctuation simulation?
I'm trying to replicate this real quantum fluctuations observation using Blender.

So far, I have used Principled Volume and Voronoi texture to create clouds. However, I can't get my head around how to animate them to look like actual random fluctuations.
If, say, I use the Mapping node, then it would just shift, rotate or scale individual clouds, whereas they have to pop in and out constantly without an obvious pattern.
Their edges are also blurry, and I couldn't achieve a sharp look with the ColorRamp.


What about setting to 4D in your textures, and play with the additionnal input ?

I'll need to render it properly, but it seems it does the trick; thanks!
What about making the clouds sharper?

Probably set the density to 0 ?

Nope, that one is responsible for the fade of the clouds. The clouds themselves are connected to the emission and are not dependent on density

The density fills the space in between with the dark blue fog. But your exemple isnt volumetrics so I dont understand your goal exactly.

(source : http://www.physics.adelaide.edu.au/theory/staff/leinweber/VisualQCD/ImprovedOperators/index.html . Context : this is a gif showing the smeared action density as a function of monte-carlo-time (not real time))

(sorry, it's probably in euclidean time, not in MCMC time)

Volume to mesh (Geometry nodes)
Simple setup
Your example shows a geometry with solid faces. Here is a simple way of creating the mesh in Geometry nodes.

Basically :

Spawn a Volume Cube with a custom density
Convert the Volume to a Mesh
Store the custom density as an attribute, to be accessed from the shading editor.

The downside is that a good quality mesh is expensive to compute. A workaround is to setup 2 different resolutions, one for viewport and one for render. Taking 1 second to compute the mesh at render is OK, but in the viewport it should be quick (real-time).
Setup with workaround
Here is the full setup with two resolutions :

Notes and blend file

I didn't spend much time on the texture controlling the density. You probably can keep your existing nodes.
With a low resolution, the mesh is quite low-poly and so the material too. But it shouldn't be a problem while working with it, it will only be blurrier.
The pink input of W in the noise texture node is a Driver.





Notes:

Animate Musgrave (Voronoi or what ever) Texture > 4D - W parametr
Render Properties > Volumes > Step Rate Viewport/Render 0.2

