How to extend surface material to volume?
How can I extend the 3D noise texture into the volume to make a 3D solid? plugging in the same surface BSDF into volume BSDF causes the object to be completely transparent.
Alternatively, how to create an object shaped like 3D noise texture?
surface only:



This is probably what you want to achieve ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/320509/how-can-i-create-a-quantum-fluctuation-simulation?noredirect=1#comment558085_320509

If I understand well your question, I guess you mean to distribute noise in a volume.
In your case you are using principled BSDF with is for surfaces and also you have connected to surface in material output (last node).
Solution:
Replace principled BSDF with Principled volume and in material output connect to volume instead of surface.
Have a look to the image, it might help.
